# MongoDB Schema with Image field

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I want to create a schema like the following in MongoDB with image field,

```
{
    _id: {},
    camera_id: ObjectId(),
    image: {},
    hour: ts_of_hour,
    day: ts_of_day
}
```

I want to use GridFs for Image field. How can i create a single Collection like this with Gridfs image field in Mongodb.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is the name of your GridFS object in your document. You will need to store/retrieve within your application logic: MongoDB won't do this automatically for you. Here is a presentation with example code on [how to manage images with GridFS](http://www.slideshare.net/marksmalley1/serving-images-with-gridfs).

Comment: That link does not answer the question in any way... and it shows only some very brief php code, which is not related to the question.

Comment: @cauchy the text of my answer answers the question, i.e., you just need a string in your document, which is the GridFS "pointer". The link simply shows an example of GridFS use.

Comment: you sir have gotten lazy. I looked at your other answers and you clearly have the knowledge but you resorted to posting a solitary link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question dont use a link to answer a question but rather to support your argument. and that slide share sucks just saying